# How to refer configmap yaml file name exits under different chart for checksum/config annotation

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am currently trying to configure the checksum/config annotation for my deployment spec. Whenever my configmap content changes, I need my deployments to happen the rolling upgrade.

```
kind: Deployment spec: template: metadata: annotations: checksum/config: {{ include (**print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml"**) . | sha256sum }}
```

Scenario :

- Chart-A : contains the ConfigMap files and other resource definitions.
- Chart-B : can be considered as a mini/generic microservice and contains the deployment.yaml file.

As part of this deployment yaml, I need to introduce the checksum annotation on the Configmap yaml that exists in Chart-A. For this, I need to give the path, but both the $.Template.BasePath and .Files.get don't solve this problem.

I need to specify the name of ConfigMap (configmap.yaml) which is present in the different directory (not in the current helm chart) while building. How can I specify the same? The relative path is not working.

```
kind: Deployment spec: template: metadata: annotations: checksum/config: {{ include ('../../../../../catalog-helm/src/main/helm/catalog/templates/openstackGlareConfiguration-configmap.yaml') . | sha256sum }}
```

This is resulting - error calling include: template: no template

helm link -
https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments

Output of helm version:

```
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.2.3", GitCommit:"8f832046e258e2cb800894579b1b3b50c2d83492", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.12"}
```

Output of kubectl version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.6", GitCommit:"dff82dc0de47299ab66c83c626e08b245ab19037", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-07-15T16:58:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.4", GitCommit:"8d8aa39598534325ad77120c120a22b3a990b5ea", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-12T20:55:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Write a build Script ( or Use maven Copy Plugin) which will move your respective configmap inside template directory. then use annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/your-configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}

Comment: I will check this Mohit, Thanks.

Comment: @MohitSharma: Is there no direct solution intead of writing a seperate scritp.